# Windows 8 periodic tile not updating

Tags: windows-8

I have created a dynamic page for Windows 8 periodic tile updates. The url for the tile is:

http://www.dealsapiens.co.uk/ws/xml.aspx?action=tile

So I try to use the following code:

```
// update the tile poll URI
var notifications = Windows.UI.Notifications;
var polledUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://www.dealsapiens.co.uk/ws/xml.aspx?action=tile");
var recurrence = notifications.PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.hour;
var tileUpdater = notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication();
tileUpdater.startPeriodicUpdate(polledUri, recurrence);
```

However, when I run and stop the add and go to Start Menu, I do not see the tile images, it just renders a black tile. Any ideas? Do I have some problem with my tile XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, you're using invalid id attribute values.  The ids correspond to positions within the tile.  For the square tile, the id should be 1; for your wide tile you want ids 1 through 5 with each corresponding to the area of the tile that should be occupied by that image.

I've adjusted your tile XML and hosted it at http://jimoneil.blob.core.windows.net/tiles/dealsapiens.xml  - give it a shot. It's working on my end.